# Dúvida sobre contexMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É o seguinte, eu preciso adicionar essas ferramentas, exatamente como mostra na imagem.

Preciso só de um empurrão, sobre como começar.

> Inserir texto
>
> Inserir Imagem
>
> Excluir (botão)

CODE

```
namespace frmLoginRPG
{
    public partial class frmMenuPrincipal : Form
    {
        private readonly Button[] _todosBotoes;
        public frmMenuPrincipal()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            //Passo 1
            
            
            _todosBotoes = _mainPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
        }
        
        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Passo 2.1
            var controles = _todosBotoes.Where(btnRifts => (btnRifts.Tag as String ?? btnRifts.Text).ContainsIgnoreCase(txtBuscarJogo.Text)).ToArray();
            //Passo 2.2
            _mainPanel.Controls.Clear();
            //Passo 2.3
            _mainPanel.Controls.AddRange(controles);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
 

        private void btnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Button button = new Button(); //criando botão
            button.Size = _todosBotoes[0].Size; //criando botão, puxando o tamanho dos outros botões
            button.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue; //definindo cor do botão
            _mainPanel.Controls.Add(button); //Adicionando botão no _mainPanel
            button.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1; //Adicionando contextMenuStrip assim que o Botão for criado.
            
            MessageBox.Show("                  CRIADO        ");
            
        }
    }

  

}
namespace MyMethod
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string source, string search)
        {
            return source.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
        }
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Você cria um `contextMenu` e define ele na propriedade do Button, no evento do click você saberá de qual `button` veio o click pelo `sender`:

```
    private void inserirTextoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = ((Button)sender).Name;
        MessageBox.Show("Você clicou para inserir no botão: " + name);
    }

    private void excluirToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = ((Button)sender).Name;
        MessageBox.Show("Você clicou para excluir o botão: " + name);
    }
```

Comment: Mas eu preciso daquelas funçoes funcionando, Excluir o botão, colocar imagem no botão, alterar descrição no botão... entendeu?

Comment: @Dário, é só você trocar o MessageBox do código do rovann pela funçao que você precisa. Em inserir por exemplo ficaria: Button btn = (Button) sender; btn.Text = text;

Comment: Presumindo que text seja uma String que você definiu, ou pediu pro usuário.

Comment: nao tenho como colocar funcionando pq o 'inserir texto' como q o usuario irá inserir ? o excluir, vai excluir da onde ? entende....rs só o conceito

Comment: Eu entendi, mas no caso não seria usuário nenhum, só eu mesmo! Excluir o botão do Panel inserir descrição de texto no botão e colocar imagem no botão. tudo através do ContextMenu

Comment: Eu não tenho um banco de dados, nada... ta bem cru

Comment: A função para excluir poderia ser algo assim: Button btn = (Button) sender; _mainPanel.Controls.Remove(btn);

Comment: Já as outras duas, você precisa receber o texto e a imagem de algum lugar. Uma opção seria abrir um novo Form passando o botao como parâmetro e dentro desse Form, alterar as propriedades necessárias como text e image.

Comment: Está faltando você projetar sua aplicação antes de desenvolver e saber cadas recurso que ela precisará. Desde a primeira pergunta que você fez onde eu respondi com exemplo onde um DataTable era origem dos botões. Agora se você precisa armazenar essas informações, editar, inserir ou excluir, nada dessa parte estática dos botões inseridas diretamente na tela faz sentido, teria que alterar essa parte toda.